# Firefox warning: Content Security Policy: Couldn’t process unknown directive ‘require-sri-for’

Tags: firefox, sub-resource-integrity

Why does Firefox tell me

> Content Security Policy: Couldn’t process unknown directive ‘require-sri-for’

when [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity#Content_Security_Policy_and_Subresource_Integrity) says they've implemented it?

The meta tag Firefox is complaining about:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="require-sri-for script;"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of version 69, Firefox no longer supports the require-sri-for CSP due to concerns about standardization status. The original answer below is only valid for versions 49-68.

---

If you look at the [compatibility tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/require-sri-for#browser_compatibility) you will see that firefox has a flag which labels this functionality as "User must explicitly enable this feature." To quote:

> From version 49: this feature is behind the security.csp.experimentalEnabled preference (needs to be set to true). To change preferences in Firefox, visit about:config.